# Why the delegates or closures often referred as true "object-oriented function pointers"?

Tags: c++, oop, delegates, closures, function-pointers

For example, considering the C#

> > Unlike function pointers in C or C++, delegates are object-oriented,
> >     type-safe, and secure.
>
> source:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Now talking about the C++ only, what is the real difference and what is missing from an OO prospective?

Also from another source

> > Most C++ programmers have never used member function pointers, and
> >     with good reason. They have their own bizarre syntax (the ->* and .*
> >     operators, for example), it's hard to find accurate information about
> >     them, and most of the things you can do with them could be done better
> >     in some other way. This is a bit scandalous: it's actually easier for
> >     a compiler writer to implement proper delegates than it is to
> >     implement member function pointers!
>
> source:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

I find that many programs in C++ uses the `->*` syntax, i don't find that this is bizarre or strange; I don't get the point about this potential about the delegates and the attack to the pointers.

Comment: @user827992: After the edit... do you still stand by *many programs in C++ use the `->*` syntax*? How often have you seen that particular syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think people find it difficult to write them, but they behave like ordinary pointers, if they are NULL then its wrong to execute them. If they are written and used properly then there is nothing wrong with them. I never really had problems with,maybe besides forgetting proper syntax.

In c++11, you can use std::function<> class which is a wrapper for function pointer. You can use it for functions, member functions, functions objects and lambdas.

for example:

```
void foo(int x);
std::function<void(int)> f=foo;
f(1);
```

or easier (works in VS2010):

```
void foo(int x);
std::function<decltype(foo)> f=foo;
f(1);
```

ref: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Answer (score 4):

The difference between a member pointer and a true closure is that a closure contains the function *and* the associated state. The two are inseparable.

A member pointer is *just* the function. In order to call a member pointer, you must *provide* the state.

It's the difference between a function pointer and a functor. The function object holds the function to be called (as an overload of `operator()`), but it can *also* have members. Those members can be private, thus providing encapsulation. The function object is an object by C++ rules, so it has an explicit lifetime. It is constructed and destructed according to C++ rules.

A function pointer has no lifetime; it always exists (unless it's NULL). It has no state to encapsulate.

Therefore, it's not a closure because it can't *close over* anything.

That's why C++11 lambdas are implemented as explicit objects. That way, they can close over things. They have encapsulated state.

Comment: So part of the problem about function pointers are about the fact that: 1) they are allocated in the heap ( no lifetime ) 2) they are pointers so they just store an address and a type for that address ( they lacks about the presence of a state ) 3) they are supposed to point to whatever address is formally correct and there is no guarantee about what they are actually pointing to. So basically the main difference between this and the delegates is the missing part about an object state that can make this a "real" object in the OO way.

Comment: @user827992: Function pointers are not heap allocated; they exist in static memory. They exist throughout the lifetime of the executable, because they are *part* of the executable. Heap allocated objects do have a lifetime; it's just entirely user-controlled.

Comment: As for #3, no; function pointers are separate from any *state*. They have no more state than global functions. A closure, *by definition*, has state (or at least potentially does). Closures can have state, function pointers cannot. That's the difference. It's not about guarantees; it's about the essential nature of what they are.

Comment: @NicolBolas In your last comment I think you meant *functions* are not heap allocated -- function pointers can be allocated on the heap and deallocated later or exist in stack memory that's been recovered or rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Member function pointers are not member functions. Function pointers in C/C++ are dangerous in the sense that they could point to deallocated memory or be set to NULL at any time. Generally they are avoided, though not always with things like boost::bind or swapping print functions.

Thus in general they aren't any more dangerous than standard pointers. However, you can oftentimes avoid using function pointers by just calling an object's member method or a static function somewhere else. It compiles to using function pointers on the inside, but you have better guarantees about the existence of that function when it gets called.

Comment: so, basically they can cause problems related to "memory leak" issues ?

Comment: @user827992 Actually kind of the opposite. Memory leaks are when you forget to free memory. NULL pointer errors are when you free it too soon (or never allocate it).

Comment: how you call the situation where a pointer points to an unwanted location? like when you pass a pointer by value instead of passing by reference and you end up having a pointer that is a local copy of the original and the original just keeps pointing to a location that your business logic doesn't compute anymore?

Comment: @user827992 That would depend on what happens to the old reference. Most of time it's just having a pointer to the wrong value, but if the old reference has been deallocated then it is usually called a bad reference error. It will oftentimes behave like a NULL pointer error, but sometimes it will just start executing random memory as though if it were a function until it segmentation faults. Because of that it can sometimes make very silly events occur if it starts in the middle of some other function.

Comment: Why the -1 with no comment as to why it's not a valid response?

Comment: don't ask me, i voted +1, i think that your reply adds something good to the topic that is discussed here.